# How to override Nginx response headers in PHP

Tags: nginx, php

I want to apply a default CSP header in nginx - basically a catch all. However, I also want to be able to override the CSP header via PHP in certain scripts. So far I've been unable to find a way to do this and the result is I get 2 headers - the first from PHP and the second from Nginx, with the last header taking preference over the first.

In nginx I have:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';";
```

Then there's a catch for the PHP files:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
```

I've tried playing around with `fastcgi_param` to see if I can get the header back from PHP and only add_header if not set, as well as trying:

```
    if ($http_content_security_policy = "") {
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';";
    }
```

But so far not winning. I assume it's a timing or access issue in Nginx in terms of the PHP header values? Any help is appreciated.

Note: I'm using Azure web apps, so I don't think I can add any modules that aren't default for Nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add_header` directive will not generate a header if the value provided is an empty string.

You can provide various values to the `add_header` statement by using a `map` block. See [`map` directive documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).

The header returned by the PHP script is available as `$upstream_http_content_security_policy`.

So the solution is to test the value returned by the PHP script using a `map` block, and set the default value only if the script returns no header.

For example:

```
map $upstream_http_content_security_policy $csp_value {
    ""  "default-src 'self';";
}
add_header Content-Security-Policy $csp_value;
```

The default header for Content-Security-Policy is only inserted if the `$upstream_http_content_security_policy` variable is empty (meaning that the script did not provide an alternative value).

Note that the `map` block must be placed outside of the `server` block. The `add_header` statement can remain where you currently define it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. This worked perfectly and I have a better understanding now of the process. Much appreciated!